# linux ssh tunnel mysql workbench

Tags: mysql, linux, ssh

I can not connect to a database because workbench keep saying Could not connect the SSH Tunnel i check log file

```
11:49:45 [INF][     SSH tunnel]: Existing SSH tunnel not found, opening  new one
11:49:47 [INF][     SSH tunnel]: Opening SSH tunnel to x.x.x.x
11:49:47 [ERR][   sshtunnel.py]: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/share/mysql-workbench/sshtunnel.py", line 231, in _connect_ssh
look_for_keys=has_key, allow_agent=has_key)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paramiko/client.py", line 306, in connect
t.start_client()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 465, in start_client
raise e
SSHException: Incompatible ssh peer (no acceptable kex algorithm)
11:49:47 [ERR][     SSH tunnel]: Authentication error opening SSH tunnel: Authentication error, unhandled exception caught in tunnel manager, please refer to logs for details
11:49:48 [INF][      WBContext]: Connection to ovs cancelled by user: Tunnel connection cancelled
```

i can connect to the remote host in terminal using the key but not in workbench.
Other people that connect to this say that they use pageant i tried looking for pageant for linux and no luck.

i am runnning linux mint 17.3 64 bit

Answer (score 0):

Pageant is for Windows. Use Seahorse or Keychain for Linux:
http://www.debianadmin.com/ssh-key-authentication-using-seahorse-gui.html
http://pwet.fr/man/linux/commandes/keychain

Comment: i looked in the keyring and the key is there.

Comment: i posted the log in the question. is there another log file i can look at?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it, like it's in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42029615/863403 so all credits go to @hansaplast

change your transport.py:

```
sudo nano /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paramiko/transport.py
```

press CTRL+W for searching for the term

```
return self._cipher_info[name]['class'].new(key, self._cipher_info[name]['mode']
```

replace

```
return self._cipher_info[name]['class'].new(key, self._cipher_info[name]['mode'], iv, counter)
```

with this

```
return self._cipher_info[name]['class'].new(key, self._cipher_info[name]['mode'], '', counter)
```

as mentioned in the [Github pull request](https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/pull/714/commits/4752287a7379da61245087ee7e35635a4e42bb3f)