# Paramiko: "FutureWarning: CTR mode needs counter parameter"

Tags: python, warnings, sftp, paramiko, python-cryptography

I am trying to use Paramiko in Python2 for transferring files through SFTP with a private SSH key but it displays this warning:

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Crypto/Cipher/blockalgo.py:141: 
FutureWarning: CTR mode needs counter parameter, not IV   self._cipher = factory.new(key, *args, **kwargs)
```

In fact it sends the file to the server but can someone explain me what this warning means?

Here is my code:

```
t = paramiko.Transport((host, port))
key = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key_file("/path/to/key.ssh") 
t.connect(username="username",password=None, pkey=key)

sftp = paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(t)
sftp.put(source, destination)

sftp.close()
t.close()
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is most likely a bug in paramiko

You can try to patch `paramiko/transport.py` with [this patch](https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/pull/714/commits/4752287a7379da61245087ee7e35635a4e42bb3f) to make the warning go away

See also the discussion [here](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=851551) which references the pull request.

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me.

1. Remove the `python-paramiko` package installed with apt:

`apt remove python-paramiko`

2. Install paramiko via pip that provides a newer obviously fixed version:

`apt install duplicity python-pip -y`

`pip install paramiko`

Comment: Why would I need to install duplicity?

Comment: @Jreisinger, duplicity is used in combination with paramiko. As you can see here: https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/search?q=duplicity&type=Issues&utf8=%E2%9C%93, many errors get resolved with a proper duplicity installtion.

Answer (score 3):

Updating Crypto package vanishes the "CTR mode needs counter parameter, not IV" warning in my case:

```
pip install -U Crypto
```

Answer (score 0):

What @hansaplast recommended worked great.
In my case, I replace `vi` to  at line 1649 in the following file:
`/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paramiko/transport.py`